# How to get value in $1 in regex to a variable for further manipulation

Tags: javascript, regex

Please let me know if $1 can be assigned to a variable for further manipulation ? I am getting matched strings in $1 but not able to do further slicing based on the matching

I have the below string:

```
var result="#02080=#04217+#04217_DUP6887","#01066=(#01047+#01111+#01048+#01118+#01049+#01050+#01121+#01128+#01131+#01141+#01138+#01148+#01053+#01062+#01054+#02080+#02048+#01064+#01063+#01065+#01051+#01052+#02062+#02069+#02072+#02079)","#02002=#01066","#02007=(#02002+#02003+#02004+#02005+#02006)","#02010=(#02007+#02008+#02009)","#04216+#04216_DUP6887=#04217+#04217_DUP6887","#04215+#04215_DUP6887=#04216+#04216_DUP6887"
```

I have regex to match areas like

```
#04215+#04215_DUP1869=
```

. My intention is to make areas like

```
#04215+#04215_DUP6887=#04216+#04216_DUP6887
```

to

```
#04215_DUP6887=#04216+#04216_DUP6887
```

In regex, I'm using pattern as below:

```
var regex2=new RegExp("([#][0]["+pgNo+"][0-9]{3}[+][#][0]["+pgNo+"][0-9]{3}[_][D][U][P][0-9]{4}[=])" ,"g");
```

```
result=result.toString().replace(regex2,'$1'+'rrrr');
```

This only appends 'rrrr' to matched places(not what I want). I need to take those matched places in $1 and slice off till '+' symbol. How can I achieve it ?

Comment: Use the syntax `.replace(regex, function(m, $1, $2, ...) {`.

Comment: Why do you have all those one-character strings inside `[]` like `[#][0]`? Just use `"#0`

Comment: And `pgNo` probably doesn't need to be in `[]` either.

Comment: Syntax? Can you please elaborate ?

Comment: [`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)